# El While infinito (Python)

Tags: python, bucles, while

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de una lista de compras con un while y varios if y elif y pues teoricamente todo bien hasta que llega la opción en la que debe cerrar el ciclo y no lo hace. Quisiera que me pudieran orientar sobre lo que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias, les dejo mi codigo:

```
accion = print("Programa Lista de la compra, ingrese un articulo para añadirlo a la lista o Q para salir: \n")
accion = None
lista= []
while accion != 'Q':
    articulo = input("Ingrese el artículo que desea añadir a la lista (Q para salir):  ")
    if articulo == 'Q':
        print("Su lista de la compra es: "+ str(lista))
    elif articulo != 'Q':
        conf=input("¿Desea agregar {} a la lista de compra?(S/N)".format(articulo))
        if conf == 'S':
            lista.append(articulo)
    else:
        print("Su Lista de la compra es " + str(lista))
```

Comment: la variable `accion` entra al ciclo con el valor `None` y nunca cambia de valor dentro del `while`, por tanto el ciclo nunca terminará. Por otro lado, pides al usuario que ingrese un artículo al inicio y desechas el valor, con lo que el primer artículo que ingresa nunca forma parte de la lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jachguate ya te explico en los comentarios que es lo que pasa con tu codigo.

En el ciclo While no actualizas en ningun momento la variable `accion`, el usuario puede escribir **Q**, pero tu programa no va a reconocer que ese comando es la señal de salida del while.

Yo solo le agregaria una sola linea en el primer condicional:

```
accion = print("Programa Lista de la compra, ingrese un articulo para añadirlo a la lista o Q para salir: \n")
accion = None
lista= []
while accion != 'Q':
    articulo = input("Ingrese el artículo que desea añadir a la lista (Q para salir):  ")
    if articulo == 'Q':
        print("Su lista de la compra es: "+ str(lista))
        #creo que con solo esta liena funciona.
        accion = 'Q'
    elif articulo != 'Q':
        conf=input("¿Desea agregar {} a la lista de compra?(S/N)".format(articulo))
        if conf == 'S':
            lista.append(articulo)
    else:
        print("Su Lista de la compra es " + str(lista))
```

Feliz noche!